# what is the best way to check user logged in or not when using token login in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I am working on authentication of an app. Which works something like this. When user pass there `userid and password` if it will receive a token. And there is another endpoint to `verify token` and then set token to the `localstorage`. From here it is available everywhere i need. Actually all the endpoint need this `access token`  to fetch data.  I am not sure whether it is right or wrong.

And I do have some issue with this process like when user sets token to `localstorage` this page redirects to dashboard But there dashboard doesn't receive data at once i need to refresh the page to see them.

This is my code.

> actions

```
export const getAccessToken = (dataToSend) => async (dispatch) => {
  var formData = ConvertToFormData(dataToSend);
  const response = await Authentication(formData);
  if (response) {
    await fetch("http://api.smartocart.com/userType", {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-cache",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${response.access_token}`,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === "admin") {
          SaveToLocalStorage("access_token", response.access_token);
        }
      });



    if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        payload: {
          access_token: response.access_token,
          refresh_token: response.refresh_token,
        },
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        buttonPressed: true,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

> index.js

```
if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  store.dispatch({
    type: "GET_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    payload: {
      access_token: token,
    },
  });
}
```

Please help me to know the right way to solve this issue any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using correctly async/await.

```
export const getAccessToken = (dataToSend) => async (dispatch) => {
  try { 
    const formData = ConvertToFormData(dataToSend);
    const authResponse = await Authentication(formData);
    const response = await fetch("http://api.smartocart.com/userType", {
          method: "GET",
          cache: "no-cache",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authResponse.access_token}`,
          },
        });

    const payload = await response.json();

    if(payload.status === 'admin' && payload.access_token) {
     SaveToLocalStorage("access_token", payload.access_token);
     dispatch({
            type: GET_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            payload: {
              access_token: payload.access_token,
              refresh_token: payload.refresh_token,
            },
          });
       } 
    }
    else {
    dispatch({
            type: ERROR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            buttonPressed: true,
    });
    }
  catch(exception) {
    console.log('Log or again emit an event')
  }
};
```

You are dispatching action before the response is received.